# Output all guesses from scipy.optimize.leastsq()

Tags: python, scipy, regression, least-squares

I'm hoping to make an animation about how the least-squares regression analysis provided by scipy.optimize.leastsq() converges on a specific result. Is there any way to get the function to, say, append to a list a tuple of guess values for each iteration until the function converges to the local minima? Or, is there a different library which includes this feature?

Below is what I have:

```
# initial guess for gaussian distributions to optimize [height, position, width].
# if more than 2 distributions required, add a new set of [h,p,w] initial parameters to 'initials' for each new distribution.
# new parameters should be of the same format for consistency; i.e. [h,p,w],[h,p,w],[h,p,w]... etc.
# A 'w' guess of 1 is typically a sufficient estimation.

initials = [6.5,13,1],[4.5,19,1]

# determines the number of gaussian functions to compute from the initial guesses
n = len(initials)

# formats initials into a 1D array
var = np.concatenate(initials)

# data matrix
M = np.array(master)

# defines a typical gaussian function, of independent variable x,
# amplitude a, position b, and width parameter c.
def gaussian(x,a,b,c):
    return a*np.exp((-(x-b)**2.0)/c**2.0)

# defines the expected resultant as a sum of intrinsic gaussian functions
def GaussSum(x, p):
    return sum(gaussian(x, p[3*k], p[3*k+1], p[3*k+2]) for k in range(n))

# defines condition of minimization, reducing the square of the difference between the data (y) and the function 'func(x,p)'
def residuals(p, y, x):
    return (y - GaussSum(x,p))**2

# executes least-squares regression analysis to optimize initial parameters
cnsts = leastsq(residuals, var, args=(M[:,1],M[:,0]))[0]
```

what I'm eventually hoping for is for 'cnsts' to be a list of tuples of every guess from the initial guess to the final guess.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Were you ever able to get these intermediary values?  I'm dealing with the exact same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to make a guess at each of the different coefficients while fitting a linear regression line, then have a list of all the coefficents that have been guessed? Similar to how a NN will back-propagate the error to better fit a model?

Linear regression isn't guessing the different coefficents. It's just calculating them... https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/#FindaLinear

Comment: Sorry, my question header might’ve been a bit misleading;  we’re using a least squares regression minimization algorithm to get from an initial guess to a converging local minimum, not just fitting a straight line through a data set (if you look at the code I included you can see that it’s actually written for an arbitrary set of superimposed gaussian functions)

Comment: Lol, I don't know what I was thinking with I typed this but I was referencing the wrong function in the question; using scipy.optimize.leastsq() not linregress.